# Inkwell doesn't work when inside Expanded widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a purple toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                width: 100,
                child: const Text("Hello"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have Expanded as the parent widget, whose child is Material and InkWell. When I set any color to the Container widget the InkWell effect disappears or I think it is being drawn below the Container widget. Is there any way to solve this. I need to set the color to the container and also have the InkWell ripple effect.

Please let me know if you have a solution. Have been struggling with it for a while. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inkwell paints the splash on to the closest Material. See the *Troubleshooting* heading on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html to fix this.

Comment: Awesome. Just now check the docs. Thanks so much. This works. Added Ink as parent instead of Container. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please mark that as "the answer" then, so I can get more meaningless points.

Comment: Sure, I had to wait 8 minutes to accept the answer. Stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept the answer before 8 minutes.